# how to calculate the distance of moving vehicles is how much?

Tags: netlogo

I want to determine the distance the vehicle traveled for comparison with other values, I should use the command / function what to calculate.
for example in the picture, I want to use the function to determine the distance d1, after one-time drive, the distance will be the last .... d2 distance riding is dn[image]

Comment: If you said `forward 3` then the distance travelled will be 3. How far that is in the x-direction and the y-direction is a matter of trigonometry and angle. You can use the primitives `dx` and `dy` to work out the actual position in terms of `xcor` and `ycor`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Perhaps JenB's comment is better for you. But here's a different kind of answer:

A simple way for a turtle to keep track of how far it has traveled is shown in this small example program:

```
turtles-own [traveled]

to example
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  ask turtles [
    repeat 5 [
      let delta random-float 1.0
      fd delta
      set traveled traveled + delta
    ]
    print traveled
  ]
end
```

Basically, every time the turtle moves, you add the amount it moved to a turtle variable.

This assumes you are using `forward` to move the turtle. If you are moving the turtle using some other method like `setxy` or `move-to`, then you will need different code.